# Hyperlinked column in grid.On click of the field an event should occur

Tags: asp.net, html, c#-4.0

I have a column in a asp grid which should be hyper-linked. Not only the header but the data bound to the column is also hyper-linked. When I click on any of the field's in the column it should trigger an event.

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="HeaderCloumnName" 
                    DataTextField="Data" DataNavigateUrlFields="link" />
```

Here "link" is an url but instead I want a method / even that should be triggered. How can I use Onclick event with hyperlink text that is fetched from the database?

Comment: client side or server side eethod/event?

Comment: server side. When i click on the hyper-linked data it should take the selected value to back end and do some data manipulation from DB and display another panel

Comment: Then go with bgs264 's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8985239/293712. That's best I know of

Answer (score 2):

You can't, as a `HyperLinkField` renders out an `<a />` tag which the browser just interprets as a link.

Instead you could use a `ButtonField` and set its `ButtonType` to a `LinkButton`, or use a `TemplateField` and add your own `LinkButton` manually into the template.

Comment: Still i need an onclick event that would let me do some functions

Comment: The GridView/DataGrid whichever you are using will fire an event - RowCommand maybe? Have a look at the events associated with the grid one of them will fire when it's clicked.